# MYSQL: Finding count of rows that meet a criteria

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table of the given format. Here I have a city and a parameter which is true if there is a football field in the city. I want to find the percentage of countries in every continent that have at least 2 cities with football stadiums.

```
Id  | Stadium|  City        |   Country |  Continent
__________________________________________________
1   | true   |  Manchester  |   UK      |  Europe

2   | true   |  London      |   UK      |  Europe

3   | false  |  Leeds       |   UK      |  Europe

4   | true   |  Berlin      |   Germany |  Europe

5   | false  |  Dubai       |   Dubai   |  Asia
```

I am new to MySQL. I can't figure out how to do this. Can someone please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use subqueries and do some like this:

```
SELECT q.Continent as continent, SUM(IF(q.qntStadiuns > 2, 1, 0))/COUNT(*) * 100 as percent
FROM
    (SELECT Continent, Country, COUNT(*) as qntStadiuns
    FROM tableName
    WHERE Stadium = true
    GROUP BY Continent, Country) AS q
GROUP BY continent
```